# Swift: Why is my conditional binding not working?

Tags: json, swift

I read the JSON file from http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/1/ and store them into **pokemonInfoDict**.

So **pokemonInfoDict** is of type **Dictionary < String, AnyObject >**

> print(pokemonInfoDict["moves"]!) has the folllow output:

```
(
    {
    "learn_type" = "tutor";
    "name" = "Bind";
    "resource_uri" = "/api/v1/move/20/";
},
    {
    "learn_type" = "machine";
    "name" = "Swords-dance";
    "resource_uri" = "/api/v1/move/14/";
}
)
```

Thus, it is a **[Dictionary < String, String >]** type

So why is my conditional binding failing to cast it as a **[Dictionary < String, String >]** type?
The print(movesArray) is not called.

```
if let movesArray = pokemonInfoDict["moves"] as? [Dictionary<String,String>] where movesArray.count > 0
{
     print(movesArray)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm been stuck on this for quite a while ...

Comment: A `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` cannot be casted to `Dictionary<String, String>` even when all the elements are `String`

Comment: Modern syntax would write this as `[[String : String]]`

Comment: I see, thanks I will keep that in mind @redent84 I tried changing the cast to AnyObject and it works..

Comment: After taking a closer look at the JSON I noticed that some of the `moves` have an additional `level` key with a numeric value. So the object is always `[Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]` rather than `[Dictionary<String,String>]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
if let movesArray = pokemonInfoDict["moves"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] where movesArray.count > 0
{
    print(movesArray)
}
```

Comment: may I know why does this conditional binding works when it seems to be a [Dictionary < String, String >]  type when i print it out? And also what data structure is [[String:AnyObject]] ?

Comment: `[[String:AnyObject]]` is an array (`[ ]`) of dictionaries (`[String:AnyObject]`).

Comment: Hi, i tried casting [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]  instead of [Dictionary<String,String>]   and it works too. Is [String:AnyObject] same as [Dictionary < String, AnyObject >] ?

Comment: Yes, [[String:AnyObject]] is same as [Dictionary < String, AnyObject >]

Comment: Ic, thank you so much for your help and everyone else as well

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
var p:Dictionary < String, AnyObject > = Dictionary()
var d1:Dictionary < String, String > = Dictionary() // explicit type
d1["learn_type"] = "tutor"
d1["name"] = "bind"
var d2 = ["learn_type":"machine", "name":"dance"] // implied type
p["moves"] = [d1, d2]
if let g = p["moves"] as? [Dictionary < String, String >] {
    print("It works!") // and it does print
}
```

so I suspect there is something strange going on with your code, and you should probably post more code.

I looked at the URL `http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/1/` following your updated answer. It is true that most of the data loaded has the type `String`. However, using standard JSON parsing:

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/1/")!) {(data, response, error) in
   let parsed = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[])
   // more code here
}
```

I found that some of the dictionaries in the `moves` array contain an entry like

```
[level:7]
```

and the type of `7` is not a `String` so Swift says that the type of `moves` must be `[Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]` despite the fact that nearly all the entries are `<String,String>`. Here is some code to check it:

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/1/")!) {(data, response, error) in
    let parsed = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[])
    if let parsed = parsed as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
        if let m2 = (parsed["moves"]) {
            if let m3 = m2 as? [AnyObject] {
                if let m4 = m3 as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] {
                    m4.forEach({m in
                        for (n,v) in m {
                            if let _ = v as? String { }
                            else { print("not a String: \(n):\(v)") }
                        }
                    })
                    print("m4 was ok")
                } else { print("m4 is wrong type") }
            } else { print("m3 is wrong type") }
        } else { print("m2 is wrong type") }
    } else { print("parsed is wrong type") }
}.resume()
```

Comment: I have updated the post with more info.. I tried your code and it works but it just seems not fail the cast on mine. Its weird because the structure is indeed  [Dictionary < String, String >]

Comment: The dictionary is not all String, String!